# Is it possible to mix a 'preference' and a preference header?

Tags: android

I am developing a list of preferences for my app. Right now, there is only one, but I am sure there will be more as it gets fleshed out. My first preference is a 'theme' selector, where you choose the background color theme for some predefined elements.

I want a dual-pane interface for my upcoming prefs, but I don't need this preference in a 'subcategeory' that preference headers use. Is there a way to add a 'preference' (via XML) to the headers list so it will appear in the root preferences? I've looked... haven't seen any examples on if this is possible. Right now all I have is a button for 'Themes', which goes to a new preferences page (another fragment it lives under) which is making 2 clicks instead of one for a preference that doesn't go under a category.

Answer (score 2):

You can can make a preference header behave like a preference, though you can't actually put a `Preference` object into the list of preference headers. All you have to do is assign an ID to the header and override `onHeaderClick()` in your PreferenceActivity.

Here's an example of how to simulate a `ListPreference` as a preference header.

*pref_headers.xml:*

```
<preference-headers
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <header
        android:id="@+id/choose_theme" 
        android:title="Theme" />
</preference-headers>
```

*MyPreferenceActivity.java:*

```
public class MyPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    private CharSequence[] mThemeOptions =
            new CharSequence[] {"Red", "Blue", "Awesome"};
    private int mSelectedTheme = 0;

    @Override
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> headers) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, headers);
        for (Header h : headers) {
            if (h.id == R.id.choose_theme) {
                h.summary = mThemeOptions[mSelectedTheme];
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onHeaderClick(Header header, int position) {
        if (header.id == R.id.choose_theme) {
            OnClickListener l = new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    mSelectedTheme = which;
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    // Trigger the summary text to be updated.
                    invalidateHeaders();
                }
            };
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setSingleChoiceItems(mThemeOptions, mSelectedTheme, l)
                    .show();
            return;
        }
        super.onHeaderClick(header, position);
    }
}
```